# Angular changeDetection not trigger

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Im working in multiple file upload component so far this is what i have:

**upload.html**

```
<div class="upload-file-wrapper nx-padding-x-2m">
    <ng-container *ngIf="progressFileInfo.length > 0">
        <div class="file-uploaded nx-margin-bottom-m" *ngFor="let progressFile of progressFileInfo">
            <span class="icon-document mpt-icon"></span>
            <div class="file-upload-info nx-padding-x-s">
                <p>{{ progressFile.fileName }}</p>
                <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="progressFile.value != 0 || progressFile.value != 100" mode="determinate" [value]="progressFile.value"></mat-progress-bar>
            </div>
            <button mat-icon-button>
                <span class="icon-trash-can mpt-icon nx-margin-0"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**upload.ts**

```
@Input() serviceId!: string;
@Input() planId!: string;
@Input() set FileSelected(files: FileList) {
    if (files) {
        this.upLoadFiles(files);
    }
}
readonly progressFileInfo: any[] = [];
private readonly _destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
constructor(
    private readonly resourceManagementService: ResourceManagementService,
    private readonly servicePlanService: ServicePlansService,
    private readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {}

ngOnInit() {}

upLoad(index: number, file: File): void {
    this.progressFileInfo[index] = { value: 0, fileName: file.name };
    this.resourceManagementService
        .uploadAdditionalDocument(this.serviceId, this.planId, file)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
        .subscribe(
            event => {
                if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    this.progressFileInfo[index].value = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
                    console.log(this.progressFileInfo);
                    this.cd.markForCheck();
                }
            },
            error => {
                this.progressFileInfo[index].value = 0;
                this.progressFileInfo[index].fileName = `Error uploading file - ${this.progressFileInfo[index].fileName}`;
            },
        );
}

upLoadFiles(files: FileList): void {
    Array.from(files).forEach((file: File, index: number) => {
        this.upLoad(index, file);
    });
}
```

**upload.service.ts**

```
uploadAdditionalDocument(serviceId: string, planId: string, file: File): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${serviceId}/plan/${planId}/api-specification/document`;

    const body: FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('file', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post<{ fileId: string }>(url, body, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'json',
        observe: 'events',
    });
}
```

the idea is to track the progress of each file uploaded and display the percentaje in the progress bar but for some reason the progress bar is alway at 100%, when there is and error in any of the request i change the name of the file to 'Error uploading file ${fileName}' and change the upload % to 0, but for some reason none of that is reflected on the view, so for some reason change detection is not trigger on the component, as you can see im using the `ChangeDetectionRef` to try to trigger the change detection manualy, but no change in the view, i forgot to say that the component is using the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

[image]

Just try without mutation

```
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                const c = this.progressFileInfo[index];
                c.value = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
                Object.assign([], this.progressFileInfo, { [index]: c });
                console.log(this.progressFileInfo);
                this.cd.detectChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

markForCheck does not trigger the change detection. It will simply mark the component to be checked next time when angular runs the change detection runs by default.

> Use detectChanges() to trigger the change detection manually instead
> of markForCheck.

Also, since you are mutating the same object, Change detection will not run by default.
Try changing the reference of the object progressFileInfo instead of mutating it.

```
if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    const exist = this.progressFileInfo;
    exist[index] = { ...exist[index], value: Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total) };
    this.progressFileInfo = [...exist]
    console.log(this.progressFileInfo);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I actually try using `detechChanges()` also but the result is the same

Comment: Try changing the reference of the array instead of mutating it.

Comment: i update the post and try without mutating the object and using `Object.assign` but the same result as before

Comment: Try using the updated answer. you need  to change the reference of the progressFileInfo.

Comment: Ok i just try the updated answer but for some reason the same result.

Comment: Can you try removing the readonly property in progressFileInfo variable

Comment: Yes i did it before try the answer you post, for some reason in this example from this post is working: [multiUpload component](https://bezkoder.com/angular-multiple-files-upload/)

Comment: I just check again the solution you post and is working, it was another issue in my code that was creating the problem